# Cannot pass specific variable to session

Tags: php, session, variables, set, meta-tags

I'm trying to do the following (I know it appears to be unnecessarily complicated, but I had to break the problem down into its bits):

page_a.php

```
$keywords = get_meta_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
$author = $keywords['author']; //"nameofauthor"
$foo = "foo";
$keywords = array ( "author" => $author, "foo" => $foo);
$_SESSION['keywords'] = $keywords;

//echo $author on page_a.php would successfully print "nameofauthor", so the variable isn't empty
```

page_b.php

```
echo $_SESSION['keywords']['author']; //echoes ""
echo $_SESSION['keywords']['foo']; //echoes "foo"
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: If you `var_dump($keywords['author']);` before assigning it to `$author`, what's the result?

Comment: I don't know if and where there is a problem, however my first question when seeing "sessions" used is, is `session_start();` in all your files and at the top?

Comment: @Fred My first thought too but one variable is echoing correctly.

Comment: @Jim You'd think that it would echo the first result and not the other due to the session being overwritten or lost, or not found?

Comment: It looks like the problem is not with session, but with what `get_meta_tags` is returning. Are you sure it is returning you the author? Add `var_dump($keywords);` after line 1 to check.

Comment: Or doing it the other way around? Such as `$keywords = $_SESSION['keywords'];` then just echo `$keywords`?

Comment: @Phas1c: I get string(12) "nameofauthor"

Comment: @Fred: echoing `$_SESSION['keywords']['author']` right after assigning it to the sesssion prints "nameofauthor" correctly.

Comment: @tobias You never answered my question 2 days ago. Is `session_start();` inside ALL your files `page_a.php` and `page_b.php` and at the top as the first line under your opening tag `<?php`?

Comment: @Fred: sorry, I was out of office. Regarding your question, of course I start the session on each page. Otherwise, I wouldn't be able to echo `$_SESSION['keywords']['foo']` - anyway, see my solution below!

Comment: @tobias No problemo. I had to ask. I'm glad you figured it out; I'd of never figured it out. Good work. Definitely worth a +1, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem to be a double-execution of the page containing the script.

In the first run, the referer was taken from the remote site (the one I need to retrieve the meta-tags from).

In the second run, the referer was taken from the script hosting site and hence, resulting in this run overwriting the tags with empty values (since no meta-tags are being used in the script itself).

To avoid the latter, I added the following lines to check whether it is the first or second execution.

```
$baseurl = parse_url($request->getBaseUrl()); //My framework's function to return the hosting system's base-url (e.g., example.com)
$referer = strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], $baseurl['host']) ? $_SESSION['referer'] : $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$keywords = get_meta_tags($referer);
```

Thanks for sharing your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

`Warning: get_meta_tags(): Filename cannot be empty`

`get_meta_tags` — Extracts all meta tag content attributes from a file and returns an array

You are not working on a file but on a global variable.

Example:
`$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');`
You probably wanted: `get_headers()`:
 - returns an array with the headers sent by the server in response to a HTTP request.

Comment: Hi davidS, I do need the tags, not the headers. And since get_meta_tags indeed is returning what I require, it still is a matter of assigning its result to the session. I do in fact receive example.com's author (and description, etc.), which I proofed by echoing $author ("nameofauthor") just before assiging it to the session. Plus, on the very same page after assigning it to the session, $_SESSION['keywords']['author'] would correctly contain $author (it echoes "nameofauthor"), yet on other pages I end up with an empty echo, whereas all's just fine when I assign a manual value...